# jquery .delegate() not firing

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I need to delegate events to a radio group because eventually Ill be dynamically adding more but I cant get the second function to fire on the initial radio buttons.

I would appreciate any help.  Im using jquery mobile 1.3.1 if that makes a difference.

HTML:

```
<form id="officeChoice">
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>office:</legend>
    <input type="radio" name="office" id="radio-choice-v-2a" value="on" checked="checked">
    <label for="radio-choice-v-2a">One</label>
    <input type="radio" name="office" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="off">
    <label for="radio-choice-v-2b">Two</label>
    <input type="radio" name="office" id="radio-choice-v-2c" value="other">
    <label for="radio-choice-v-2c">Three</label>
</fieldset>
```

Jquery:

```
//This Works!

$('input[name=office]:radio').on('click',  function () {
var $value = $(this).val();
alert($value);
});

//This Doesnt

$('#officeChoice').on('click','input[name=office]:radio',  function () {
    var $value = $(this).val();
    alert($value);
});
```

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/adam123/9wPc8/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jWzGz/

Replace **`click`** with **`change`** and everything will work like charm.

```
$('#officeChoice').on('change','input[name=office]:radio',  function () {
    var $value = $(this).val();
    alert($value);
});
```

Comment: This is because how custom radio buttons are implemented in jQuery Mobile and how events are propagated to hidden elements.

Comment: @roasted I can see that now in firebug.  Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Jquery mobile change the html rendered, if you click exactily on the `radio button`, it works.

Just check the rendered HTML code and see what's going on.

```
<div class="ui-radio">
    <input type="radio" name="office" id="radio-choice-v-2b" value="off">
    <label for="radio-choice-v-2b" data-corners="true" data-shadow="false" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-icon="radio-on" data-theme="c" data-mini="false" class="ui-radio-on ui-btn ui-btn-hover-c ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all ui-fullsize ui-btn-icon-left"><span class="ui-btn-inner"><span class="ui-btn-text">Two</span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-radio-on ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span></span>
    </label>
</div>
```

So, as suggested by Gajotres, use change event instead.

Comment: His fiddle is correct, this is a jQuery Mobile question. jQuery and jQuery Mobile are different products.